# text information retrieve result analysis dataset (text)

Tags: semantic-web, information-retrieval

I had created the text semantic search engine. However, I cannot find the data set which is labeled so that I can evaluate the information retrieve of my system.

Is there any public available document (text) which is labeled. As I would need the text document to evaluate  the information retrieve  result. (recall, precision, F1 value...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I do research in this direction. In all my research, i have used [AOL dataset](http://www.researchpipeline.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=AOL_Search_Query_Logs) which consists of ~20M web queries collected from ~650k users over three months (March 01, 2006 to May 31, 2006). The data is sorted by anonymous user ID and sequentially arranged.

The data set includes `{AnonID, Query, QueryTime, ItemRank, ClickURL}`. More details can be found in the link mentioned above. I am interested to know how you have implemented and if possible, share your engine's code. I am also interested to know the performance on AOL dataset in your search engine.

You can find the dataset in my [git repository](https://github.com/wasiahmad/Hierarchical-Privacy-Preserving-IR/blob/master/docs/requirements.md). Thanks!